# Setting maximum height of a label while having Grid.Row height set to auto

Tags: c#, xamarin

I have a label within a grid. I would like the label to be dynamic(I don't want to specify the height).

```
<Grid>
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  
    ...
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    ...
    <Label Text="{Binding Description}" 
           LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>  
    ...
</Grid>
```

When my description has very little text, it's height is approximately 20(1 row), if there's alot of content, max height should be 40(2 rows).

At the moment the height is set to auto. It works fine for 1-2 row description, but if it's more than two rows, it's too large. May I ask how should I handle large rows while trying to maintain auto height.

Comment: did you try any control like `FlowDocument`? i'm not familiar with xamarin but know wpf.

Comment: Hey.Is my answer helpful?

Answer (score 0):

You  can  set the `MaxHeight` of label.Refer to the following code.

> create a subclass of label.And rewrite the method **OnMeasure**.

```
public class MyLabel:Label
{      
    public MyLabel()
    {

    }

    protected override SizeRequest OnMeasure(double widthConstraint, double heightConstraint)
    {

        if(heightConstraint>40)
        {
            return new SizeRequest(new Size(widthConstraint,40));
        }

        return base.OnMeasure(widthConstraint, heightConstraint);
    }


}
```

> And in xaml.cs

```
<Grid>
 <Grid.RowDefinitions>
 ...
    <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>  
 ...
 </Grid.RowDefinitions>
 ...
 <local:MyLabel Text="{Binding Description}" 
       LineBreakMode="TailTruncation"/>  
 ...
</Grid>
```